# Stuck with php function not returning any data

Tags: php, return, return-value, php-7.4

I am expecting the below code to return `hi` when the project is run.But it's not returning anything .There is no error also.I've started the wamp server. How can i fix this?I'm very new to this. Anyone can tell me this?

**functions.php**

```
<?php

function getDate($orderDate, $oderTime) {
    return "hi";
}

?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";
require "config.php";
require "functions.php";

getDate(var_export($days),var_export($Time));
```

**config.php**

```
<?php

$Time = "1";
$days = ["Sat", "Sun"];
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the return value.  What do you want to do?  Print it to the screen?

Comment: `echo getDate(var_export($days),var_export($Time));` (assuming you want to display it on screen). The value is returned from the function, but your main code block isn't using it for anything.

Comment: @Devon yes.i need to print the return value in screen

Comment: _Side note:_ Why are you using `var_export()` when passing in the arguments? Why not just pass the variables directly: `getDate($days, $Time);`?

Comment: @ADyson  when echo,it now returns the function's value but the values of $days & 4Time is also getting displayed. I need the function returning value only needs to be printed in screen

Comment: @user17189691  A return statement doesn't return to the screen, they return to the calling function.   You would need to leverage the return value in an additional call (echo as displayed above).

Comment: _"but the values of $days & 4Time is also getting displayed"_ - that's because `var_export`, without the second parameter set to true, writes to the output buffer directly. And it _returns_ `null` in that case, so you practically called your function  as `getDate(null, null);` here.

Comment: `echo getDate($days,$Time);`. What did you think `var_export()` is for, exactly? Sorry I didn't really pay attention to that the first time.

Comment: [var_export()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) - _"**Outputs** or returns a parsable string representation of a variable"_ - It outputs it as default.

Answer (score 1):

when you use return the return value wil not shown on your screen till you **echo** it out, like this

```
echo getDate(var_export($days),var_export($Time));
```

and by the way you can replace **return** keyword in your function with **echo**
in this case you don't need to write `echo getDate(var_export($days),var_export($Time));`

just type `getDate(var_export($days),var_export($Time));`

Comment: They should remove the `var_export()` as well since it doesn't really make sense here.

Comment: @M.Eriksson you are right